# Does AWS EMR 5.23.0 has resource manager in HA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am new for AWS EMR. I have a few Flink's jobs which is written using Flink 1.7.1 and I want yarn based HA using EMR.

I would like to know how I can turn on HA for resource manager in AWS EMR.

Similarly how I can have secondary name node on EMR.

Does EMR 5.23.x provides HA?

If not, Is there any roadmap to provide this provision?